# How to map two DStreams two one in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

This is probably a very simple question but I didn't find any direct methods to do it in the Spark Streaming API docs.

Lets say I have two JavaDStreams like so:

```
JavaDStream<String> stream1;
JavaDStream<String> stream2;
```

If I want to map one of these two to another JavaDStream String,stream1 for example, I just do this:

```
 JavaDStream<String> stream1mapping=stream1.map(new Function<String,String>() {
                @Override
                public <String> call(
                        <String> s) throws Exception {
               //do operations on s
               ...
               return new_string;
               }
               });
```

My question now is, how can I make it so that I use two JavaDstreams instead of one, as an input to map, perform operations on the two, like comparing values etc, and return a single JavaDstream as a result?

So something like this for example:

```
 JavaDStream<String> bothstreamsmapping=(stream1 and stream2).map(new Function<String,String>() {
                @Override
                public <String> call(
                        <String> s1, s2) throws Exception {
               //do operations on s1 and s2
               ...
               return s3 //a single string as a result of operating with s1 and s2;
               }
               });
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: you would normally use `join` for that, but your streams will need to have a (k,v) format. In your usecase, how would you know which `s1` value goes with a `s2` value?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `stream1.union(stream2)`. The doc for union is here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.html#union(org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)

Comment: departing from the description, I'd think that OP needs something like a 'zip'